# Tracking Pixel TransactionAmount

Tags: magento-1.8, php

Hello I'm trying to fix this pixel in my success.phtml, can anybody help me so I can fill in the right value in TransactionID and TransactionAmount, the amount should be the subtotal.

```
<img src="https://ts.tradetracker.net/?cid=1XXXX&pid=2XXXX&tid={transactionID}&tam={transactionAmount}alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$orderNumber = $order->getIncrementId();
$subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
?>
<img src="https://ts.tradetracker.net/?cid=1XXXX&pid=2XXXX&tid=<?php echo $orderNumber;?>&tam=<?php echo $subtotal;?>alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Comment: That didnt work :/

Comment: can you be more specific? what does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Im sorry, the order numer and the subtotal came up with no information to our affiliate.

Comment: Hmmm...try with `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());` instead of `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());`

Comment: Tried but it came back with same results

Answer (score 1):

You should use the order data from the session:

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($orderId);

$total = $order->getData('grand_total');
?>
<img src="https://ts.tradetracker.net/?cid=1XXXX&pid=2XXXX&tid=<?= $orderId ?>&tam=<?= $total ?>alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Comment: That didnt return anything

Comment: That's weird, this exact same code works perfectly in our 1.7.0.2 store. Maybe this doesn't work in 1.8 then. You're sure the data is still in the sessions? I.e. you're not refreshing the success page without making an order first?